# mdBootStrap and NodeJS Directory Structure Inquiry

Tags: node.js, bootstrap-modal

I've read over the documentation and I cannot seem to find a clear answer as to the proper directory structure for a node application (insert downvotes here).

When I create an application directory off the root.  All js, css, and img directories will be based of this application directory.  My confusion comes in where when I install mdBootStrap using npm it creates the node_modules and mdbootstrap directory as expected, but then down these chains of directories it creates it's own js and css directory as well.

So back in the main application directory, in the HTML files, when I reference bootstrap and jquery files for example, am I forced to reference all the way down the node_modules directory, or has the mdBootStrap actually become my new application directory.

Comment: I cannot make mdbootstrap work in ejs files. Any ideas here?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using express you can expose your node_modules dependancy folder through your routing by adding a static route.

```
var application = express();
application.use('/mdbootstrap', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/mdbootstrap'));
```

Other options are using gulp build tasks to include the node_module dependancies in your output build.